# how to find out last cidr address of a cidr range

Tags: networking

hope you are doing great I have a CIDR range `10.88.0.0/24`

so for this CIDR range, I would like to calculate the last CIDR address I knew there are some online tools to do that but I would like to know the login how we can calculate last CIDR address using any programing language.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Trying to keep it Ubuntu related ... [sipcalc](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/sipcalc.1.html) is an IP subnet calculator that is available for install in Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt install sipcalc
```

It can be used like so:

```
sipcalc ip-address/netmask
```

Example usage:

```
$ sipcalc 10.88.0.0/24
-[ipv4 : 10.88.0.0/24] - 0

[CIDR]
Host address        - 10.88.0.0
Host address (decimal)  - 173539328
Host address (hex)  - A580000
Network address     - 10.88.0.0
Network mask        - 255.255.255.0
Network mask (bits) - 24
Network mask (hex)  - FFFFFF00
Broadcast address   - 10.88.0.255
Cisco wildcard      - 0.0.0.255
Addresses in network    - 256
Network range       - 10.88.0.0 - 10.88.0.255
Usable range        - 10.88.0.1 - 10.88.0.254

-
```

or:

```
$ sipcalc 10.88.0.0/24 | awk '/Usable range/ {print $NF}'
10.88.0.254
```

to only print the last usable address for example.

Answer (score 1):

I will show with your example: 10.88.0.0/24

To do it manually, first convert everything to bit notation:

```
10.88.0.0 = 00001010.01011000.00000000.00000000
```

next search the 24th bit and convert everything right of it to ones:

```
00001010.01011000.00000000.11111111
```

return to decimal

```
10.88.0.255
```

the highest possible IP is one less: **10.88.0.254**

Programatically need some binary operations:

```
11111111.11111111.11111111.11111111 >> 24 (right shift 24times)
00000000.00000000.00000000.11111111
```

```
00001010.01011000.00000000.00000000 + (or)
00000000.00000000.00000000.11111111
-----------------------------------
00001010.01011000.00000000.11111111
```

```
00001010.01011000.00000000.11111111 -1
-----------------------------------
00001010.01011000.00000000.11111110 = 10.88.0.254
```

You now might image, why the notation with the netmask is used:
10.88.0.0/255.255.255.0

Invert Netmask and do the "or".

```
010.088.000.000 + (or)
000.000.000.255
---------------
010.088.000.255 -1 (minus one)
---------------
010.088.000.254
```

To get the lowest:

```
010.088.000.000 * (and)
255.255.255.000
---------------
010.088.000.000 +1 (plus one)
---------------
010.088.000.001
```